# Automatically closing <a> tags within Knockout comment

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

```
<!-- ko if: IsNew() === true -->
    <a href="#" class="new" data-bind="click:$root.markRead">
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: IsNew() === false -->
    <a href="#">
<!-- /ko -->
    <div class="notification-item">
....
    </div>
</a>
```

I am using knockout comments in my view to determine which  tag should be shown. When I view the page, whichever  tag gets shown gets closed within the same comment block. Has anyone experienced this before? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual elements must nest properly, just like real elements.

You can use conditional bindings to add the `class` attribute and `click` event:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="css: {'new': IsNew() }, click: IsNew() ? $root.markRead : null">
<div class="notification-item">
....
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured I needed to do it this way, just wasn't sure how.

Comment: To extend my previous question, it seems as I update the IsNew() property on some of my elements, it does not trigger these statements to re-evaluate. Do you have an explanation for why that may be?

Comment: How are you updating IsNew()?

Comment: Does it help if you use `css: {'new': IsNew }` instead of `css: {'new': IsNew() }`?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, it was updating IsNew as expected, just another part of my code that wasn't running. Thanks again for the help.